# Installing Scala's compiler, sbt, on a Mac gives me a permission error

Tags: macos, scala, homebrew

I tried to install Scala compiler, sbt, on a Mac OS. But I got a permission error. Any idea?

```
mac610881:~ $ brew install sbt
==> Downloading https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.0.3/sbt-1.0.3.tg
Already downloaded: /Users/.../Library/Caches/Homebrew/sbt-1.0.3.tgz
Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (conf/sbtopts, /usr/local/etc/sbtopts)
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your Homebrew installation. You should (actually, need to) be able to write to `/usr/local`, as that's where everything managed by Homebrew lives.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of Jorg W Mittag,  I solved this issue using

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/etc
```